# SQLite JavaFX INSERT Into Syntax error near x

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

I have a line of code to insert many variables into a database called GoodDB. for some reason I am unable to get it to work and get a syntax error.

I have read multiple threads where my code is 1:1 yet for some reason it still does not work for me

```
public void submitButton (ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:--Location--");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO GooDB (Date, UID, prodCode, TableNr, TableTwo, Line, Var, Comment, CommentTwo, Person, Dept, Qty) VALUES '" + dDate.getValue() + "', '" + tfuID.getText() + "', '" +
                tfprodCode.getText() + "', '" + tfTableNr.getText() + "', '" + tfLine.getText() + "', '" + tfcommentTwo.getText() + "', '" + taComm.getText() + "', '" + cbPerson.getValue() + "', '" + cbTableTwo.getValue() + "', '" +
                cbDept.getValue() + "', '" + cbQty.getValue() + "'");

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("u good");
        alert.setHeaderText("u good");
        alert.setContentText(null);
        alert.showAndWait();

    } catch (SQLException e){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("DB Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("DB Connection Failed");
        alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Upon entering data I get Error message described in "catch" showing

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "'null'": syntax error)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `()` around the values to insert. Furthermore I recommend using `PreparedStatement` to make sure string literals are properly quoted.

Comment: Thank you @fabian, it was the ( ) :)